# MySQL: how to prevent insertion of a row with all columns = NULL?

Tags: mysql, null, definition

In my MySQL table, every column by itself can be NULL, but there must be at least one column with a non-NULL value. At the moment, I am wrapping an insert statement in a stored procedure which prevents insertion of all-NULL rows, but that of course does not keep anyone from using native INSERT statements, circumventing my wrapper procedure.

Is there a 'native' way to define the table with that constraint ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MySQL doesn't enforce check constraints, you may want to emulate one with a trigger. I suggest checking out this MySQL Forge article:

- [Triggers : Emulating Check Constraints](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers#Emulating_Check_Constraints)

The idea is this to move your check logic to a trigger. If the check fails, call a stored procedure that fails by raising a unique key violation. This allows us to return a descriptive error message back to the client.

Your trigger will probably look something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER check_not_all_null BEFORE INSERT ON your_table FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF COALESCE(field_1, field_2, field_3) IS NOT NULL THEN
      CALL fail('All fields cannot be null');
   END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

We need to make the `fail` sproc raise a unique key violation in order to have the `INSERT` aborted when the check fails. The above mentioned article suggests creating a memory table defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `Error` (                                                               
   `ErrorGID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,                               
   `Message`  varchar(128) default NULL,                                
   `Created`  timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
              ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,           
    PRIMARY KEY (`ErrorGID`),                                                   
    UNIQUE KEY `MessageIndex` (`Message`)
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED
```

Then the `fail` sproc could be implemented as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `fail`(_message VARCHAR(128))
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO error (message) VALUES (_message);
  INSERT INTO error (message) VALUES (_message);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The double `INSERT` will ensure that the unique key violation is raised. If the same message already exists in the table, the violation will get raised on the first `INSERT`, but it doesn't matter as long as it fails.

We can try the `fail` sproc from the command line:

```
mysql> CALL fail('All fields cannot be null');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'All fields cannot be null' for key 2
```

The good news is that we get back a readable error message. However we don't get back the correct error code, and we don't really have a "duplicate entry". This is obviously one limitation of this method, especially when updating or inserting records in a procedure which uses error handling, in particular handling the `1062 Duplicate Entry` error specifically.

Answer (score 3):

grant execute permissions only so users or your application user can only call stored procs !

Answer (score 2):

add simple check constraint

```
CHECK(COALESCE(Field1, Field2, ... FieldN) IS NOT NULL)
```

UPDATE:

Found that mysql does not support check constraint (parse, but ignore), one is possible workaround: using trigger (look to http://db4free.blogspot.com/2006/01/emulating-check-constraints.html)

Comment: Check constraints aren't supported in all versions of MySQL, unfortunately :(

Comment: @Daniel, thanks. was very surprised. check parsed, but does not used. :(